# Capture empty columns in multiline string via regex

Tags: python, text-parsing

Can someone help me to write a regex for the following, I need to create a regex which catchup value in all of the below colums as well as the empty ones, which could come as ''

I am new to regex but I tried many thing as per my knowledge but coulnt figure it out.

```
string = '''
Local Address   Port  Port Type  Probes     Drops      CtrlProbes Discard Protocol SendersCnt 
1.1.1.1         777   Permanent  9854579    0          9854677                                
2.2.2.2         15000 Dynamic    6569029    1          656905     ON      IPSLA    2          
3.3.3.3         15000 Dynamic    6569003    0          656903     OFF     IPSLA    2          
4.4.4.4         15000 Dynamic    6569029    0          656904     ON      IPSLA    2          
5.5.5.5         15000 Dynamic    1259435    0          125945     ON      IPSLA    2           
'''
```

I want to achieve this output

```
{
    'local_addr': '1.1.1.1',
    'port': '777',
    'port_type': 'Permanent',
    'probes': '6569029',
    'drops': '1',
    'ctrl_probes': '656905',
    'discard': '',
    'protocol': '',
    'sender_cnt': ''
}
{
    'local_addr': '2.2.2.2',
    'port': '15000',
    'port_type': 'Dynamic',
    'probes': '6569029',
    'drops': '1',
    'ctrl_probes': '656905',
    'discard': 'ON',
    'protocol': 'IPSLA',
    'sender_cnt': '2'
}
{
    'local_addr': '3.3.3.3',
    'port': '15000',
    'port_type': 'Dynamic',
    'probes': '6569003',
    'drops': '0',
    'ctrl_probes': '656903',
    'discard': 'OFF',
    'protocol': 'IPSLA',
    'sender_cnt': '2'
}
{
    'local_addr': '4.4.4.4',
    'port': '15000',
    'port_type': 'Dynamic',
    'probes': '6569029',
    'drops': '0',
    'ctrl_probes': '656904',
    'discard': 'ON',
    'protocol': 'IPSLA',
    'sender_cnt': '2'
}
{
    'local_addr': '5.5.5.5',
    'port': '15000',
    'port_type': 'Dynamic',
    'probes': '1259435',
    'drops': '0',
    'ctrl_probes': '125945',
    'discard': 'ON',
    'protocol': 'IPSLA',
    'sender_cnt': '2'
}
```

this is best one I could up come but again not good as it is going over to the next line and make next ip as the other group.

```
my_regex = r^(?P<local_addr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(?P<port>\d+)\s+(?P<port_type>[A-Z]\w+)\s+(?P<probes>\d+)\s+(?P<drops>\d+)\s+(?P<ctrl_probes>\S*)\s*(?P<discard>\S+)\s*(?P<protocol>IPSLA|\s+)\s+(?P<sender_cnt>\d+)\s+
```

I was using re module in python and doing the match using re.match

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `\s` matches any whitespaces, use a space or `[ \t]` to match literal spaces/tabs.

Comment: Is the aim to have a dataframe at the end?

Comment: thank you for the quick response, I am more concern about the matching the missing data e.g empty columns in second line of the above string

Comment: @Onyambu, no I am trying to create a structure data with key/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex. Do the following:

```
import pandas as pd, io

(pd.read_table(io.StringIO(string.replace('Local Address', 'Local_Address').
     replace('Port Type', 'Port_Type')), sep = ' +', engine = 'python').
     replace({None:''}).to_dict('records'))

Out[]: 
[{'Local_Address': '1.1.1.1',
  'Port': 666,
  'Port_Type': 'Permanent',
  'Probes': 9854579,
  'Drops': 0,
  'CtrlProbes': 9854677,
  'Discard': '',
  'Protocol': '',
  'SendersCnt': ''},
 {'Local_Address': '2.2.2.2',
  'Port': 17000,
  'Port_Type': 'Dynamic',
  'Probes': 6569029,
  'Drops': 1,
  'CtrlProbes': 656905,
  'Discard': 'ON',
  'Protocol': 'IPSLA',
  'SendersCnt': 2.0},
 {'Local_Address': '3.3.3.3',
  'Port': 17000,
  'Port_Type': 'Dynamic',
  'Probes': 6569003,
  'Drops': 0,
  'CtrlProbes': 656903,
  'Discard': 'OFF',
  'Protocol': 'IPSLA',
  'SendersCnt': 2.0},
 {'Local_Address': '4.4.4.4',
  'Port': 17000,
  'Port_Type': 'Dynamic',
  'Probes': 6569029,
  'Drops': 0,
  'CtrlProbes': 656904,
  'Discard': 'ON',
  'Protocol': 'IPSLA',
  'SendersCnt': 2.0}]
```

Comment: thank you for this, I will take a look at this but I am actually trying to use regex here rather than panda, can you make something with regex too?

Comment: I am getting NaN for the first dict item Senderscnt and values 2 coming as 2.0, how to handle them ?

Comment: 'SendersCnt': nan for empty value and for 2, 'SendersCnt': 2.0